# React Webpack loader unable to load class

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, webpack, babeljs

I have two typescript packages, a React application and an infrastructure package. The React app depends on the infrastructure package (via npm link at the moment). I just added a new class to the infrastructure package and I'm getting the following error when I run my React app:

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (4:8)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin/loader/index.js
 * ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
|
| export class Job {
>   active: boolean;
|   address: string;
|   coordinates: any;
```

Every solution I've been able to find has been fixed through tweaks in their webpack configuration files, however I am not using webpack in either of my packages (although it appears React is using webpack under the hood). Other questions appear to have the error where they are using the `??` operator in their code, which I am not using in this case.

Job class causing failures:

```
export class Job {
  active: boolean;
  address: string;
  coordinates: any;
  title: string;
  description: string;
  startDate: Date;
  endDate: Date;
  userId: number;
  id: number;

  constructor(data: any) {
    this.active = data.active;
    this.address = data.address;
    this.coordinates = data.coordinates;
    this.title = data.title;
    this.description = data.description;
    this.startDate = data.start_date;
    this.endDate = data.end_date;
    this.userId = data.user_id;
    this.id = data.id;
  }

  getLatitude = () => {
    return this.coordinates.x;
  };

  getLongitude = () => {
    return this.coordinates.y;
  };

  toGeoJSON = () => {
    return {
      type: "Feature",
      geometry: {
        type: "Point",
        coordinates: [this.getLongitude(), this.getLatitude()],
      },
      properties: {
        id: this.id,
        title: this.title,
        description: this.description,
        address: this.address,
      },
    };
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, React uses webpack to build the project.

This message is telling you that an additional loader is required in the configuration. The details can be found in the repository of the module(s) in the error message.

https://github.com/pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin
note the top message in the repository

> An EXPERIMENTAL Webpack plugin to enable "Fast Refresh" (also known as
> Hot Reloading) for React components.
> This plugin is not 100% stable. We're hoping to land a v1 release soon - please help us by reporting any issues you've encountered!

if you used the Create React App to get started you'll need to eject it, which will produce some webpack config files that you can edit

you'll need to do the same for source-map-loader
https://github.com/webpack-contrib/source-map-loader

however you could likely just remove those packages with no impact, however they could be sub dependencies of some other library you've installed which makes things trickier.

- there is apparently another way other than ejecting but I've not tried it
- The job class isn't the cause of the error but maybe it's using the problematic packages

To summarize: you need to eject the CRA and apply the webpack configs OR determine if you even need these packages and if not just remove them.

Comment: After ejecting the CRA, what webpack configs would need to be applied? The ones indicated in other answers?

Comment: What is your hunch on the solution that does not require ejecting? I find it really hard to believe that react cannot handle a dependency that uses class constructs with typescript.

Comment: the ejection should generate some webpack.config.js files for dev and prod, how to the apply the loaders is written in their respective repository READMEs. Theres a package called 'rewire' that may work for you but I never tried it. React and CRA are different things the CRA is just a quick start most people eject once their project reaches a level of complexity or need to use an unsupported library. Why these specific libraries dont work inside the CRA I don't know.